Using fetch API to return all values instead of just the last value
I am trying to access two API end points
let locationURL = 'https://ghibliapi.vercel.app/locations';
let filmURL = 'https://ghibliapi.vercel.app/films';
I fetch the location ID and pass it into a variable
fetch(locationURL)
.then(function(response){
  return response.json();
}).then(function(locationData){
  locationData.forEach(function(locationDetails){
    locationID = locationDetails.films[0].split('/')[4]
    return locationID;
    //console.log('Data from Location API:', locationID);
  })

//then i use the fetch method to pick up film values based on the location ID
  fetch(`https://ghibliapi.vercel.app/films/${locationID}`)
  .then(function(response){
    return response.json();
  }).then(function(filmDetails){
    console.log(filmDetails.id);
  });
});

but in the last fetch() call, I only get the last ID instead of all IDs
I tried using the forEach() and map() methods in the second API call, but I don't get any response. Is there some variable declaration or method that I am missing

fetch calls are asynchronous, the second fetch call is executed before the first fetch call inside the forEach() loop completes. This is why you are only getting the last ID instead of all IDs.
To fix the issue, you can use Promise.all() to wait for all the fetch requests to complete before proceeding:


let locationURL = 'https://ghibliapi.vercel.app/locations';
let filmURL = 'https://ghibliapi.vercel.app/films';

fetch(locationURL)
  .then(function(response){
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(locationData){
    //map each location to a promise that fetches the film details
    const filmPromises = locationData.map(function(locationDetails){
      const locationID = locationDetails.films[0].split('/')[4];
      return fetch(`https://ghibliapi.vercel.app/films/${locationID}`)
        .then(function(response){
          return response.json();
        });
    });

    //wait for all film detail requests to complete
    return Promise.all(filmPromises);
  })
  .then(function(allFilmDetails){
    //now allFilmDetails contains an array of film details for each location
    console.log(allFilmDetails);
  })
  .catch(function(error){
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });




Thank you Mamun for the answer. Will try to implement the way you suggested and update.
